# storing form data from landing page to csv file for later use in mail client

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I have been looking all afternoon, and no results I have found worked for me, maybe I am not integrating the code correctly. I have a script for a landing page for wifi, and the php for the auth page, forwarding to the net. I want to use php somewhere in the middle to store the form data from the landing page to a csv file on the server to use later in an email client. Each time a user enters a new set of details, the csv is updated with a new row.

The form:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
 $_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];          //user's mac address
 $_SESSION['ap'] = $_GET['ap'];          //AP mac
 $_SESSION['ssid'] = $_GET['ssid'];      //ssid the user is on (POST 
 2.3.2)
 $_SESSION['time'] = $_GET['t'];         //time the user attempted a 
 request of the portal
 $_SESSION['refURL'] = $_GET['url'];     //url the user attempted to 
 reach
 $_SESSION['loggingin'] = "unique key";  //key to use to check if the 
 user used this form or not
                // -- prevents them from simply going to 
 /authorized.php on their own

 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Portal Page Example</title>
 </head>

 <body>
<form name="login" action="authorized.php" method="post">
<input id="Name" type="text" name="name" value="Name" />
<input id="Email" type="text" name="email" value="Email" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Connect" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The auth page:

```
   <?php

session_start();

function sendAuthorization($id, $minutes)
{
$unifiServer = "https://unifi-IP:8443";
$unifiUser = "UniFi Username";
$unifiPass = "UniFi Password";

// Start Curl for login
$ch = curl_init();
// We are posting data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
// Set up cookies
$cookie_file = "/tmp/unifi_cookie";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
// Allow Self Signed Certs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
// Force SSL3 only
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
// Login to the UniFi controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "login=login&username=$unifiUser&password=$unifiPass");
// send login command
curl_exec ($ch);

// Send user to authorize and the time allowed
$data = json_encode(array(
    'cmd'=>'authorize-guest',
    'mac'=>$id,
    'minutes'=>$minutes));

// Send the command to the API
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/api/cmd/stamgr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data);
curl_exec ($ch);

// Logout of the UniFi Controller
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/logout');
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);
}

if ($_SESSION['loggingin'] == "unique key") // Check to see if the form 
has been posted to
{
ob_start();
    sendAuthorization($_SESSION['id'], (12*60)); //authorizing user for 
12 hours
ob_end_clean();
unset($_SESSION['loggingin']);
}

?>
<p>Connecting to the network...</p>
<script>
//allow time for the authorization to go through
setTimeout("location.href='http://www.Google.com'",6000);
</script>
```

This is nearly the exact solution: https://daveismyname.blog/form-to-csv-with-php but it downloads the csv instead of storing it with the web page, and I need it to append a row of data every time someone else fills out the form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it, just for anyone else trying to do this, here is the answer. Put this code in at the top of your processing php file, and edit to your own needs:

```
    <?php
$Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));
$Email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Email']));

if (!empty($Name) || !empty($Email)) {
$csvData = $Name . "," . $Email;
$fp = fopen("formdata.csv","a");
if (fp)
{
fwrite($fp,$csvData."\n");
fclose($fp);
}

}
```